# @property or self.property to set a property with an accessor?

Tags: ruby

Which is better practice; manipulating properties with accessors by `@property` or `self.property`?

Comment: This is a good question, and something I've wondered myself. Most code I see uses the @class_variable directly, but I've often wondered if it would be better to use the accessors the way client code would, just from a style/readability perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just using straight accessors, then stick to `@property` (unless you come from Python and are turned off by the `@` sigil hehe) otherwise:

It's entirely up to you. But `self.property` can be useful in some circumstances where you need to ensure the property is initially set up:

```
def property
    @property ||= []
end

# don't need to check if @property is `nil` first
self.property << "hello"
```

Also beware that there is a slight overhead to using `self.property` over `@property` as `self.property` is a method call.

**NOTE:** The reason i'm using `self.property` over just `property` is because the corresponding setter method `property=` requires an explicit receiver: `self.property=`, so I choose to use the explicit receiver with both.